# Selenium 4.3.0 get the element of button type to python

Tags: python, selenium

I am struggling on how to get the button type element in this example, so that I can be able to test it using selenium in python.

```
<button class="login-button signin-button button-primary" type="submit"><div class="signin-text">Sign in</div></button>
```

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

import time


PATH = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH)

driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/login")


driver.find_element("name", "login_password").send_keys("123456")
driver.find_element("type", "submit").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()


print("Test Completed Successfully ")
```

I think the code changed because of the selenium version? I need help guys Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such selector type as `"type"`. You can either use another locator for Submit button e.g.

```
driver.find_element("xpath", "//button[@type='submit']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

or this form submitting approach

```
input_field = driver.find_element("name", "login_password")
input_field.send_keys("123456")
input_field.submit()
```

Comment: Please try to explain the question clearly you said `struggling on how to get the button type element in this example`  that means you wanted to get the type attribute

Answer (score 0):

you can try below xpath

```
click_button = driver.find_element(By.X_Path, "//button[contains(@class, 'login-button signin-button')]")
print(click_button.get_attribute('type'))
```